# Simplifying Expression Factorial Expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factorial

I'm confused as how I'm meant to simplify this:$$\frac{(n-2)!}{(n-2-r)!}$$

I have other factorial questions where the variable isn't present in the top factorial like the question above and I'm trying to figure out how I simplify.

Thanks

Comment: $$(n-2)(n-3)\dots(n-2-r+1)$$

Comment: What do you mean by the ...? How did you get the r in there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments, here is a useful hint:

If $r \geq 0$, then 
$$\frac{(n-2)!}{(n-2-r)!} = \frac{(n-2)(n-3) \dots (n-2-r + 1)(n-2-r)\dots (2)(1)}{(n-2-r)!}$$

If the $r$ in the expression makes it confusing, try letting $r$ equal a positive integer.  Say, $r = 2$.

Comment: Ok, I see what you're saying. But how far does it go down before it becomes $$(n-2-r)!$$? Like is the answer (n-2)(n-3)...(n-1-r)!?

Comment: @frog1944 Like I said, pick some real numbers and try it out!

Comment: I did, but I don't see a correlation to where I can simplify it to (n - x)!, not (n-2)(n-3)...(n-1-r).

Comment: @frog1944 As the other answer points out as well, there is no such way, unless you want to define an ascending factorial; this should make sense because the denominator is dividing out fewer (later) terms than are in the numerator.

Comment: Oh, I understand. Thank you very much @phatty :)

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
\frac{(n-2)!}{(n-2-r)!} &=\frac{(n-2)!}{(n-(2+r))!} \\
&= \frac{(n-2)(n-(2+1))\dotsm(n-(2+(r-1)))(n-(2+r))!}{(n-(2+r))!}\\
&=(n-2)(n-3)\dotsm(n-1-r)\\
&=\prod_{k = 0}^{r-1}(n-(2+k))\\
&=\prod_{k=0}^{r-1}(n-2-k)
\end{align*}

For example, let $r = 3$. Then
\begin{align*}
\frac{(n-2)!}{(n-2-3)!}&=\frac{(n-2)(n-3)(n-4)(n-5)!}{(n-5)!}\\
&=(n-2)(n-3)(n-4)
\end{align*}

Using the formula
$$\prod_{k = 0}^{3-1} (n-2-k) = \prod_{k=0}^2(n-2-k) = (n-2-0)(n-2-1)(n-2-2) = (n-2)(n-3)(n-4).$$